# Migrate DOMBuilder setEntityResolver method in xerces 2.7 to xerces 3.x

Tags: xerces, xerces-c

How can we migrate **setEntityResolver(DOMEntityResolver* const handler)** method in **DOMBuilder** of xerces 2.7 to xerces 3.x.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I am able to find the replacement for **setEntityResolver(DOMEntityResolver* const handler)** method in **DOMBuilder** in xerces c 2.7.

The equalent for it in xerces 3.x is :

Replace **DOMBuilder** with **DOMLSParser**.

then replace "setEntityResolver" by setting parameter as below.

**void DOMLSParserImpl::setParameter(const XMLCh* name, const void* value)**

Here "name" should be "XMLUni::fgDOMResourceResolver" and "value" is your handler.